# Projecting onto a convex set

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $C$ be a convex set containing the origin, let $A \in R^{n \times n}, x \in R^n$. Show that:
$$||{P_C(Ax)}|| \leq \sup_{u \in C \cap B} u^TAx$$
$$||{P_C(Ax)}|| \leq \sup_{u \in C \cap B, v \in C \cap B} u^TAv||x||$$

where $P_C(z) =\arg \min_{x\in C} ||x-z||_2$ and $B$ is the euclidean ball.

Both of them looks intuitive to me geometrically, but I am unable to derive them. If I assume that $Ax \in C$, then the inequality converts to equality. However I don't know how to handle the projection. Hints would suffice regarding how to proceed mathematically.

Answer (score 1):

The formula does not look correct.

Take $C = [0,{1 \over 2}] \subset \mathbb{R}$, $A=1$ and $x = {1\over 2}$.

Then $P_C(Ax) = {1 \over 2}$ and $\sup_{u \in B \cap C} u^TA x= {1 \over 4}$.

(We do have
$\|P_X(Ax)\| \le \sup_{u \in B} u^T Ax $.)

Comment: You are correct! However after going through the problem again, I saw that $C$ is not only convex but its a cone. I think it does hold for cones.